# How to fetch just one time ( stop fetching data after one is fetched )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to get data from online API -  https://api.randomuser.me/
it gets random data every time.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  var [user, setUser] = useState()
  fetch('https://api.randomuser.me/')
   .then(res => {return res.json()})
   .then(data => setUser(data.results[0].gender)) 

// if i write: .then(data => console.log(data.results[0].gender)) it console log 2 times, i want to fetch data just one time no 2 times

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {user}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Display `{user}` is changing every second, but I want to fetch just one time  not every second.

Comment: Every time it resolves you update the state which rerenders the component which makes a new fetch which updates the state which... Read about useEffect.

Comment: componentDidMount or useEffect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use useEffect, using an empty square brackets as a second parameter to fetch only once:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  var [user, setUser] = useState()
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch('https://api.randomuser.me/')
    .then(res => {return res.json()})
    .then(data => setUser(data.results[0].gender)) 
  },[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {user}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```